Are US-based research publishers not allowed to publish research papers from some institutions/firms?
Are US-based research publishers not allowed by US law/regulation to publish research papers whose authors are affiliated with some institutions/firms? Assume that no money or other form of financial incentive is being exchanged, and that publications are only made available on the publisher's website.

You mean in case of sanctions? See Elsevier actions following US sanctions on Iran and Are academic associations obliged to comply with the US government?

@Anyon thanks, any kind of law/regulation.
